# Authentication for iCal feeds

Tags: 6, feeds, authentication-authorization

I have a calendar feed (using the Drupal Calendar module) on a site and I'd like to add this calendar to Google Calendar. I have this working for a publicly accessible calendar and it works fine.

The problem now is that my calendar is only accessible for authenticated users and should remain so. I see no way to authenticate the application accessing a feed and therefore can't access that calendar from Google Calendar.

Is there any way to provide credentials in the feed url or something similar?

Comment: Would using something like OpenID create a session that authenticates with both the Google account attempting to access the calendar and the associated user account on the site?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Secure remote access to an RSS page via HTTP authentication using the [Secure Site](http://drupal.org/project/securesite) module.

> This module allows you to authenticate users with a browser-based password (HTTP Auth). You can restrict access to the site by role and choose to secure restricted pages or the entire site. This means the site will be inaccessible to search engines and other crawlers, but you can still allow access to certain users.